# Positioning on the bottom for iphone5

Tags: ios, iphone-5

I'm getting really confused here. My data picker is not positioning properly on the bottom of the screen. It's ok on 3,5' but not ok for 4'. I can't use autolayout. I hope the language won't get you confused. It's not relevant in this case.

**This is how it looks on size: Freeform**
[image: editor - size: Freeform]

**And here is a screen from editor. Size: Retina 4 Fullscreen. Other settings not changed**
[image: editor - size: Retina 4 Fullscreen]

**And Finaly. This is how it actually looks on iphone5 simulator**
[image: iphone5 simulator screen]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried adjust the Autosizing?

Comment: what's the Autosizing settings on the superview of your picker?

Comment: the superview it's supposed to stretch on the whole screen

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
somecomponent.frame = cgrectmake(0,320,somecomponent.width,self.view.frame.size.height-(navbarheight+statusbarheight+tabbar height))
```